# Changing CMakeCache variables from CMakeLists

Tags: cmake

I'm very new to CMake and trying to learn it for a project I'm working on. I'm trying to understand the relationship between `CMakeCache.txt` and `CMakeLists.txt`.

I know that `CMakeLists.txt` will generate the `CMakeCache.txt` file and that it is possible to edit variables in `CMakeCache.txt`. My question is, is it possible to edit those variables by editing parameters in the `CMakeLists.txt` file.

My application is this: I want to change the value of `CMAKE_SKIP_RPATH:BOOL=NO` to `CMAKE_SKIP_RPATH:BOOL=YES`. Can I do that from `CMakeLists.txt`?

Comment: `can I only change that manually every reload?` What is an "reload"?

Comment: I saw it linked from here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/cmakelists-txt-file.html , the site says to reload the project after editing CMakeLists.txt. I guess I don't fully understand how the CMakeCache gets changed. Is it changed every time I run make on my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify value of any variable at `CMakeCache.txt` from your `CMakeLists.txt` file. CMake exposes [set()](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.18/command/set.html) function with configurable parameters to achieve that. In particular, you can control validity of your cache variable through `CACHE` and `FORCE` options for this function

In your case, put the following statement in your `CMakeLists.txt` file to achieve the modification you want

`set(CMAKE_SKIP_RPATH YES CACHE BOOL "Skip RPATH" FORCE)`

Using `CACHE` option will let you add a cache variable if not exists. Using `FORCE` option will let you override value of existing cache variable at `CMakeCache.txt`. For detailed description about the parameters, please look at the link mentioned above